# WiFi AP mode. Is AP bradcasting SSID all the time or when it receives the request from the station

Tags: ieee-802.11, broadcast, ap

WiFi AP mode. Is AP bradcasting SSID all the time or only when it receives the request from the station?

I cant find the answer and maybe someone of you guys know the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In infrastructure mode, WiFi access points send beacons every 100 mS announcing their presence.  The beacon will contain the SSID(s) unless it's been disabled.